# Looking for a laptop with the required performances to use the Adobe premiere software please?

Tags: premiere, adobe, performance, laptop

I want to start learning  editing, I'm looking for a laptop with the required performances to use the Adobe premiere software? Any advices please!

Comment: Welcome! Adobe publishes minimum system requirements, that should be a good starting point. Beyond that, to get you the best answer possible, you should probably narrow your question down. Are there specific components you are debating between? Is there a specific problem you are having finding a suitable laptop? What is your budget? Any additional details you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: I advise to have at least 16 GByte RAM (because the OS and other tools will require RAM too). See here for requirements: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html

Comment: You may also be interested by https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

HAdobe publish this information on their website - see this link or below: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html

It's pretty simple, personally I would use the recommended specifications as a minimum in a professional environment.  If it's for personal learning, then it's your call how much you spend, but don't get anything less than the minimum.  Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much  have a great day

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you feel it answers the question :)